# Xcode Unlock “SDKSettings.plist”?

Tags: xcode6, plist, unlock

**Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d)** how do Unlock “SDKSettings.plist”? so I may edit it.

I have change the permissions yet I still get the same message

"Could not add write permission to the file because you do not own it. Try modifying the permissions of the file in the Finder or Terminal".